# What are changes in field lines after two plates of capacitors are connected?

Tags: capacitor, wire, electric-field

I recently came along to know about capacitors and their ability to store charges, also I studied about their electric field, I want to know what changes in electric fields will happen after we connect two plates of capacitors in two different scenarios.

Case-1: This is an field line diagram of capacitor before we connect their plates via conducting wire.
[image]

Case-2: When plates are non parallel and then conducting wire is attached.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When the wire is attached, the capacitor will discharge. The charges on one plate will transfer to the other, leaving no net electric field (assuming the capacitor is net neutral, like the one shown in your first image).